# Half circle animation start on button click

Tags: javascript, html, animation, onclick

I'm trying to get my circle loader running. But didn't found how to get the animation running when clicking the <kbd>Try it</kbd> button.

Any ideas?

```
<div class="chart-skills">
  <div class="liElem" id="eins"></div>
</div>

<div class="chart-skills" id="bottom">
  <div class="liElem" id="zwei"></div>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Here the code: https://jsfiddle.net/pzc41skn/

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can achieve an animation on clicking of the button:

```js
function myFunction() {
  $('.liElem').remove();
  $(".chart-skills").html('<div class="liElem" id="eins"></div>');
}
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 16px/1.5 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  padding: 130px 0 0 0;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}


/* RESET STYLES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

.chart-skills {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.chart-skills *,
.chart-skills::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* CHART-SKILLS STYLES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

.chart-skills {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 175px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.chart-skills::before,
.chart-skills::after {
  position: absolute;
}

.chart-skills::before {
  content: '';
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border: 45px solid rgba(211, 211, 211, .3);
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 175px;
  border-top-right-radius: 175px;
}

.chart-skills::after {
  content: '';
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 10px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: cadetblue;
}

.chart-skills .liElem {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border: 45px solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 175px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 175px;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: .4s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.chart-skills #eins {
  z-index: 4;
  border-color: green;
  animation-name: rotate-one;
  animation-delay: .4s;
}

.chart-skills #zwei {
  z-index: 4;
  border-color: green;
  animation-name: rotate-one;
  animation-delay: .8s;
}



@keyframes rotate-one {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    /**
     * 32% => 57.6deg
     * 57.6 + 21.6 => 79.2deg
     */
  }
}

#bottom {
    transform: scale(-1);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-skills">
  <div class="liElem" id="eins"></div>

</div>

<div class="chart-skills" id="bottom">
  <div class="liElem" id="zwei"></div>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped me understanding. There is no other way without doing it without ajax.